# Error in Deleting fields document in firestore from collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a code in flutter, which will delete document in firestore from collection in firebase. This code deletes the fields from documents. I have a delete button to delete all documents. On clicking button the document and its elements is not deleting

```
final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
  void delete() {
    firestoreInstance.collection("stall").add(
        {
              "name" : FieldValue.delete(),
              "stalltype":FieldValue.delete(),
              "buildingflatnumber":FieldValue.delete(),
              "email" : FieldValue.delete()
        }).then((value){
      print(value.documentID);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete specific field in document or trying to delete the whole document..??

Comment: I am trying to delete whole document

Answer (score 1):

To delete a document in firestore use

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("chats").doc("ROOM_1")  
    .delete();
```

Change the collection name and document ID

Comment: You're welcome.  If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see What should I do when someone answers my question?